# Running multiple databricks notebooks concurrently

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline that triggers a Databricks notebook.
Inside this notebook, I have the following code to unmount / mount storage,

```
# Unmount and mount storage
mnt_point = "/mnt"
out_mnt_point = "/out_mnt"

# Unmount storage, if any
for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts():
    if (mount.mountPoint == mnt_point):
        dbutils.fs.unmount(mnt_point)
    elif (mount.mountPoint == out_mnt_point):
        dbutils.fs.unmount(out_mnt_point)

# Mount storage for input
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = f"wasbs://" + input_folder + "@xxx.blob.core.windows.net",
    mount_point = mnt_point,
    extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.xxx.blob.core.windows.net": azure_account_key }
)

# Mount storage for output
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = f"wasbs://" + output_folder + "@xxx.blob.core.windows.net",
    mount_point = out_mnt_point,
    extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.xxx.blob.core.windows.net": azure_account_key }
)
```

My question is that, if there are multiple instances of the pipeline are running concurrently, will this affect each other (e.g. one notebook is mounting and the other is unmounting and make the other process fail)? Or does each instance has it's own specific isolated resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Running the same notebook simultaneously to unmount and mount containers in azure data factory, they are considered as separate notebook runs.
- However, since the code is accessing the same resources (blob storage containers), notebooks running simultaneously is causing error.
- I have used a for each activity with batch execution to run databricks notebook activity to execute notebook activity simultaneously for demonstration.

[image]

- Now, when this is executed, the activities fail apart from one in this case:

[image]

- When I open the runs to check for error, the message says that `Directory already mounted: /mnt/ip`.

[image]

- This is because the simultaneous notebook execution is causing some of the mount operations to occur before others in respective notebook runs. So, there is great chance for notebook run to fail in case of simultaneous execution.

**UPDATE:**

Try using the following code:

```
# Unmount and mount storage
azure_account_key = 'SRzAYuN2/aRJuSdHkwSXxXIE3qpBl0ekvtVSQ4BKqFAi+z2SM86qrUM3rt5tD3s68m450n/aledC+AStTrzdBw=='
mnt_point = "/mnt/ip"
out_mnt_point = "/mnt/op"

ip_mount = 0
op_mount = 0


for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts():
    if(ip_mount ==0 or op_mount ==0):
        if (mount.mountPoint == mnt_point):
            ip_mount+=1
        elif (mount.mountPoint == out_mnt_point):
            op_mount+=1
    
else:
    if(ip_mount==0):
        dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = f"wasbs://" + input_folder + "@xxx.blob.core.windows.net",
    mount_point = mnt_point,
    extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.xxx.blob.core.windows.net": azure_account_key }
)
        
    if(op_mount==0):
        dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = f"wasbs://" + output_folder + "@xxx.blob.core.windows.net",
    mount_point = out_mnt_point,
    extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.xxx.blob.core.windows.net": azure_account_key }
)
```

- Running the notebook with above code simultaneously did not throw any error:

[image]

NOTE: The case is same for even simultaneous pipeline runs as well instead of simultaneous activity runs as demonstrated above.

Comment: So what is the best practice for this? Since initially the storage is not mounted... should i just check if the mount point is available then just use it, no need to unmount and mount ? What if there is another notebook trying to mount using the same name ?

Comment: Hey @rcs, an error (same as the above error message) occurs when there is an attempt to mount an already mounted storage account container. Writing conditional statements to use the already mounted storage account should work without any issue. Because, if it is already mounted, then there is no need to unmount and mount it again (Since you are using the same mount name and container name anyway).

Comment: What's going to happen if there are 2 different notebooks using the same mount name ? Are they treating this mount separately?

Comment: If they are running simultaneously, then one of the notebook run might create the mount point before another. Which will throw an error in the second notebook run as the resource is already mounted

Comment: Hey @rcs, I have given an updated code which you may give a try.